# How to share the same view between two jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have two `JTable` horizontally positioned that shares the same row selection model. Only the right one is inside a`JScrollPane` with a vertical scrollbar.

I need to share the same view for both tables, so when necessary, also force the scrollbar to move up or down, to maintain aligned the views.

Comment: So you need two tables scrolling in sync essentially?

Comment: Exactly. But only the right table has a scrollbar and is inside a scrollpane.

Comment: What if you have both tables with equal height taking up a 100% of their parent container, and scroll pane as parent of that one parent container? This way you scroll the container rather than tables, so no need to sync potentially.

Comment: Both tables have the same row count. So I should try to add the JTables inside a container (JPanel?) and then add the panel inside a JScrollPane? The problem is that I needed to fix the first column of the JTable (that's why I made two JTables)

Comment: Yes, this is roughly what I'm suggesting: rather than syncing scrollers of two tables, make a parent element which will be scrolled instead. You'll have something like `ScrollPane > [Panel > [TableA, TableB]]`. I'm not sure if that works from the box, it this solution feels more natural to me.

Comment: I solved using this piece of code ;)   getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if ( getSelectedRow() != -1 ) {
                    Rectangle cellRect = getCellRect(getSelectedRow(), 0, true);
                    main.scrollRectToVisible(cellRect);
                }
            }
        });

Comment: I doubt this piece of code covers all cases: it will work differently when scrolling from top to bottom and from bottom to top. Even more specifically, it relies on having a row selected at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that I needed to fix the first column of the JTable (that's why I made two JTables)

So then you can add the first table as the "row header" of the scrollpane. Then both components will scroll in sync as both the row header and viewport are part of the scroll pane.

See [Fixed Column Table](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/) for a reusable implementation of this approach that creates the table uses in the row header for you.

Comment: I already used that as example, but I was missing propertyChange and stateChanged method implementations. Thanks, now it works better.